# List of tag synonyms and tags to be burninated or removed

Tags: discussion, tag, tag-synonyms

We'll need to merge tags/clean up. In the answer below is a list of tags that need to be turned into synonyms.

Concerning which tag should be made 'dominant', [this answer](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/28/128) says:

> The practice on similar sites (e.g. Judaism ) is to make the English word a synonym for the transliteration. In that case the tag [marriage](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marriage) on a question will be automatically replaced with the tag [nikah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nikah).

Comment: Related: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/72/removing-some-tags

Comment: what was the need for this question?

Comment: @Ashu Mainly to centralize the synonomizing of tags, but I added on burnination as well afterwards. Notice the other question does not focus on creating tag synonyms.

Comment: i belive everything about tags should be in one place so i suggest one question for it.

Comment: I agree, this is redundant, either that or this should be closed.

Comment: Please post *separate questions* for each set of tags that should be retagged / destroyed. This becomes impossible to track otherwise. Use [tag:retag-request], [tag:burninate] to categorize them.

Answer (score 2):

Feel free to add to this list! Also, please cross out tags that have already been made synonyms of.

The format is:

```
[tag:main_tag] <- [tag:synonym_1], [tag:synonym_2], ...
```

---

### Suggestions

- [nikah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nikah) <- [marriage](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marriage)
- [law](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) <- [islamic-rules](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-rules), [punishment](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punishment)
- [salat](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salat) <- [praying](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/praying), [prayer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prayer), [worship](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worship) (praying/prayer is ambiguous; could also refer to [dua](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dua))
- [dua](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dua) <- [praying](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/praying), [prayer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prayer), [worship](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worship) (praying/prayer is ambiguous; could also refer to [salat](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salat))
- [sin-or-not](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin-or-not) <- [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin)
- [sharia](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia) <- [halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal), [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram),  [islamic-rules](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-rules), [law](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law)
- [rasul](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rasul) <- [nabi](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nabi), [prophet](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prophet)
- [prophet-muhammad](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prophet-muhammad) <- [muhammad](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muhammad)
- [shia-islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shia-islam)  <-  [shiite](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shiite)
- [caliph](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caliph)   <-   [caliphet](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caliphet)
- [hadd](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hadd)  <--  [hadd-punishment](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hadd-punishment)

  ### To Consider
- [zakat](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zakat), [sadaqah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sadaqah), [charity](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charity)
- [hudud](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hudud), [punishment](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punishment)

### Manual retagging

Please retag questions with the following tags (**where appropriate**) before synonymizing:

- [source-identification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-identification) <- [citation-needed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citation-needed)
- [rasul](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rasul) <- [prophet](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prophet), [rasul](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rasul), [nabi](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nabi)

---

### Burninate

Remove the following tags from existence:

- [citation-needed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citation-needed)
- [reference-needed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-needed)
- [injustice](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/injustice)

Comment: added a few tags

Comment: @Dynamic I think [tag:citation-needed] is a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) and should be removed completely.

Comment: I agree. It should be burninated.

Comment: I don't agree with all of these. [halal] and [haram] should not be synonyms of [sharia]. They should all be merged into [sharia].

Comment: Also, we should keep [prayer] and [praying] as it's own tag.

Comment: @Dynamic Making them synonyms is basically the same as 'merging' the tags.

Comment: No it isn't because merging the tag makes sure that there is only one tag with that meaning.

Comment: Merging is a moderator-only feature that effectively retags a bunch of questions without leaving any trace of the original in the revision history. Unless there are a lot of them, you can accomplish the same thing by editing. Synonyms prevent the use of a tag *in the future* by automatically changing it to the synonymous tag when the post or edit is submitted.